# How can I get the row selected in my gridview to display in my text boxes?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview

I have got a `Gridview` that display's only certain columns from the database table.  There is a select button and delete button in my `GridView` as well.

This is the code for the `GridView`

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewClient" runat="server" DataKeyNames="FirstName"
     OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridViewClient_SelectedIndexChanged"
     OnRowDeleting="GridViewClient_RowDeleting">
  <Columns>
     <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Update" ShowSelectButton="True" />
     <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Delete" ShowDeleteButton="True" />
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Then when the user selects the `select` button it should then display the entire table in the text boxes.

This is the code for the `select` button:

```
protected void GridViewClient_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    EditClient.Visible = true;
    GridViewRow row = GridViewClient.SelectedRow;
    string constr = @"string";
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tbl_newclient"))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                sdr.Read();
                txtFirstName.Text = sdr["FirstName"].ToString();
                txtLastName.Text = sdr["LastName"].ToString();
                txtContactNumber.Text = sdr["ContactNumber"].ToString();
                txtEmailAddress.Text = sdr["EmailAddress"].ToString();
                txtAddress.Text = sdr["Address"].ToString();
                txtRestrictions.Text = sdr["Restrictions"].ToString();
                txtThirdPartySupport.Text = sdr["ThirdPartySupport"].ToString();
                txtBasicNotes.Text = sdr["BasicNotes"].ToString();
            }
            con.Close();
        }
    }
    Update.Visible = true;
}
```

The texboxes are hidden on page load and will only be visible on `select`
What happens now is that when I click on the `select` button on any row the first row of the `GridView` displays in the text box?

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what you are asking as i can't see all your code but i think the issue may be that you are only reading the first row with the data reader. you could try something like this

```
using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
   if (sdr.HasRows)
   {
      while (sdr.Read())
      {
         //I'm not sure what you want to do here? i've just addede to the existing text in the textbox
         txtFirstName.Text += sdr["FirstName"].ToString();
         txtLastName.Text += sdr["LastName"].ToString();
         txtContactNumber.Text += sdr["ContactNumber"].ToString();
         txtEmailAddress.Text += sdr["EmailAddress"].ToString();
         txtAddress.Text += sdr["Address"].ToString();
         txtRestrictions.Text += sdr["Restrictions"].ToString();
         txtThirdPartySupport.Text += sdr["ThirdPartySupport"].ToString();
         txtBasicNotes.Text += sdr["BasicNotes"].ToString();
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have `primarykey` of table `tbl_newclient` in your `Gridview`. Then on select take the primary key from `gridview` and append a where condition on your `sql query` then it should return the desired data.

```
    protected void GridViewClient_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     EditClient.Visible = true;
     var primarykey = GridViewClient.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text; // 0 cell index primary key
     string constr = @"string";
     using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
     {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tbl_newclient where yourprimarykey=@primarykey"))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@primarykey", primarykey);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
           using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
           {
             if (sdr.HasRows)
              {
                 while (sdr.Read())
                   {
                    txtFirstName.Text = sdr["FirstName"].ToString();
                    txtLastName.Text = sdr["LastName"].ToString();
                    txtContactNumber.Text = sdr["ContactNumber"].ToString();
                    txtEmailAddress.Text = sdr["EmailAddress"].ToString();
                    txtAddress.Text = sdr["Address"].ToString();
                    txtRestrictions.Text = sdr["Restrictions"].ToString();
                    txtThirdPartySupport.Text = sdr["ThirdPartySupport"].ToString();
                    txtBasicNotes.Text = sdr["BasicNotes"].ToString();
                   }
              }
         }
         con.Close();
        }
    }
    Update.Visible = true;
    }
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the explanation, but what happens now is that the text boxes appear but there is now data in them from the selected gridview row?